Treating inflammation necessary or optional?
This is not medical advice.
Is anti inflammatory therapy in ACUTE injuries or infections necessary or optional?
Shortly:
Could you please provide me with literature that definitely shows better outcomes with antiinflammatory treatment in acute injuries and infections? I know this is specific for the pathology, but I wanna get a few instances where a benefit can be shown. (I know of only one example in ICU covid patients which are treated with dexamethasone against cytokine storm.)
Also considering that there is some data that shows increase of infection complications.
I wonder why it is seen as so essential to prescribe NSAID and the optionality is not communicated to the patient. For example when I suffered bursitis olecrani, suspectedly bacterial, my doctor advised me to take ibuprofen for the inflammation. I don´t get the reasoning and did not take it. This question is inspired by a biologySE question, where a patient made the observation with physiotherapists wanting to decrease inflammation and asked whether this made even sense.
If you feel like my observation is wrong and inflammation is not unnecessarily treated please also let me know.
(Background:
We know that immune response to injury and infection are highly conserved mechanisms throughout a range of species. Self evidently, organisms were confronted with injuries and infections that warrant a finely tuned immune response already at an early stage of their development.
Those cellular responses are energetically demanding and cause collateral damage hence its rational to assume that over millions of years, dysfunctional and overarching responses would have been eliminated by natural selection.
The pain prevents us from stressing the affected area. The inflammation increases blood flow which facilitates your immune cells to restore damaged material and pathogens. Once the damage associated molecular patterns (DAMPs) or pathogen associated molecular patterns (PAMPs) are cleared up, the inflammatory phase switches to the resolution phase, where immune cells adapt an anti inflammatory phenotype to restore normal tissue homeostasis.
we can hypothesise that our bodies are well equipped to deal with all sorts of infections and injuries. Infection is a little different as, the co- evolution of pathogens prevents ideal adaptation. But if we look in the literature we see clear indications that e.g. treating a fever the mortality often increases. Though the data for humans is not as clear. But there even was one trial that was stopped because so much more people died in the antipyresis group. Another example is giving NSAIDs in soft tissue infection which increases complications.
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC4775098/#S12
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35820685/ https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC4879924/
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC4056101/
There are some concerns that NSAIDs negatively impact bone healing, though this seems to be clinically not relevant.
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC8568409/
However if we think about the cellular pathways which are inhibited we should be aware that the enzymes that produce pain and inflammation mediating prostaglandins also produce resolving factors. The resolution of inflammation is an actively regulated deactivation of proinflammatory immune cells that is necessary to restore normal function. There are mouse data which suggest increased chronification with NSAID use and some correlational data in humans as well.
https://www.medcentral.com/meds/pain/inflammation-NSAIDs-could-prevent-acute-pain-transition-to-chronic-pain)

Using an absolute like necessary will - of course - be answered in the negative. Sometimes it does need to be treated, sometimes not. "I wonder why it is seen as so essential to prescribe NSAID and the optionality is not communicated to the patient." Huh? Do you sit in on medical consultations and take notes, keeping count? Can you back this up? -1 for exaggeration and cherry picking.

"its rational to assume that over millions of years, dysfunctional and overarching responses would have been eliminated by natural selection." - not if the organism still had the vigor of youth and reproduced before that became relevant. If evolutionary reasoning is to be employed, don't disregard important things like relative lifespans  over evolutionary time.

@anongoodnurse please give me explicit examples where the outcome is improved? Excluding chronic and autoimmune cases. Well its personal experience as I said bursitis and scaphoid nonunion surgery where they gave me 14 metamizol and acetaminophen for a week , not communicated optional (took 3, is it necessary and why?) and people I know who take it in the believe it helps them heal for infections and injuries as the common narrative assumes that our bodies overreact per default.

@Jiminy Cricket: I don´t see this applying here. Infection and Injury hits organisms at every age. If the physiologic response would not allow for optimal chances of survival, it certainly is a strong driver of selection. (not rational reasoning but look at macrocilix maia, if evolution can select for that, how would it not select for animals that heal faster and can therefore escape predators or not die of infection?)

Personal anecdote isn't fact, nor do "people you know" constitute all patients. The scaphoid is notorious for non-union, even with the proper surgery because of its limited blood supply. This is starting to look like a rant. And, for the third time, it is not my responsibility to provide sources for (my) comments. Comments are not integral to answers, and this isn't a discussion forum.

you are being hostile, and apparently don't wanna be helpful, please let others who might have knowledge and wana help answer my questions and keep out if you feel that its nonsensical. you are contradicting and don't want to understand my reasoning as your scaphoid comment shows which had nothing to do with what I am looking for.

Excuse me? I'm not calling you names or making accusations (except that you have an axe to grind). My comments can't prohibit anyone from answering your question(s). I misunderstood your comment about your scaphoid, apologies. Disagreement isn't hostility except perhaps to those who resent it or misinterpret it as a personal attack. I do disagree with your premises; you aren't in the consultation room with every doctor/patient. Saying we believe NSAIDS essential and don't give patients options is absurd.

great. I acknowledged my wrongs and explained myself. maybe we can now start discussing this on a purely scientific level. So can I assume that you agree that this medication in acute situations is optional or whats your view?

@Lukas4235 - Again, this isn't a discussion forum, and to someone who has maligned me as you have after one negative interaction on another site, I'm not interested in any more arguments with you. Remember this? I had been nothing but kind to you. Sad.
